# session variable inside another variable - how?

Tags: php, session, variables, syntax

I have a script that displays countries in different languages. For example "United Kingdom" in Spanish would be "Reino Unido", etc. Every language is stored in a different table, like "name_es" for Spanish or "name_en" for English. The correct table is then selected through a session value stored for each user. What I have is this:

```
    if ($countries_id)
    {
        $sql_select_countries = $this->query_silent("SELECT name_".$_SESSION['language']." as name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "countries WHERE
            id IN (" . $countries_id . ")");

        if ($sql_select_countries)
        {
            while ($country_details = $this->fetch_array($sql_select_countries))
            {   
                $countries_array[] = $country_details['name'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that the problem line is this:

```
$countries_array[] = $country_details['name'];
```

I need it to be something like

```
$countries_array[] = $country_details['name_$_SESSION['language']'];
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax :(

Comment: `query_silent()` - I like the name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to concatenate the string 'name_' with the vale stored in session?

```
$countries_array[] = $country_details['name_'.$_SESSION['language']];
```

I think if you add some speech marks and curly brackets you can do this:

```
$countries_array[] = $country_details["name_{$_SESSION['language']}"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$countries_array[] = $country_details[$_SESSION["language"]];
```